# EmailAddress model in Django allauth?

Tags: django, django-models, django-allauth, dj-rest-auth

I just started using Django allauth, and I noticed that it created a new accounts_emailaddresses table. I understand this is useful for email confirmation, but if feels like this is a source of denormalization in our database.

Our current `User` model already has an email field. It seems like now I have to maintain the state of both `User` and `allauth.EmailAddress` models now.

For example, when a user changes emails, I need to change the User model and also mark the new email as primary in `EmailAddress`

This seems really annoying...what is the best practice in this case? Should I remove email field from `User`? I'm wondering how most people handle this.

Comment: interesting, I'd like to know too